# How to show selected value from database and show in dropdownlist using codeigniter and bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

When I select the all data of a product by it's product_id. and load product data in a form for an update. but here I cannot set selected drop-down list value in this case.

here, is my view

```
      <form action="<?php //echo base_url().'admin_product/pro_update/'?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Title :</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span5 m-wrap" placeholder="Product title" name="title" value="<?php echo $item[0]['p_title']?>" />

           <h6 style="color:red"><?php echo form_error('title')?></h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Category :</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <select name="cat" id="cat">

              <option value="">--Select Category--</option>

            <?php foreach($cat as $c):?>

    <option value="<?php echo $c->cat_id?>"><?php echo $c->cat_name;?>//selected set value here</option>
   <?php endforeach;?>

            </select>
            <h6 style="color:red"><?php echo form_error('cat')?></h6>
          </div>
        </div>
```

here is my controller code,

```
 public function pro_edit($id)
{
    $p['item']=$this->ap->product_update($id);
    $p['cat']=$this->ap->up_cat();
    $p['color']=$this->ap->up_color();  
   $this->load->view('layouts/header',$p);
   $this->load->view('admin/product_update',$p);
   $this->load->view('layouts/footer',$p);
}
```

and model code,

```
public function product_update($id)
{
    $this->db->select('p_title,p_description,p_category,p_stock_quantity,p_pprice,p_sprice,p_size_variant,cat_name,v_color,v_size,p_id');
    $this->db->from('tbl_product');
    $this->db->join('tbl_category','tbl_product.p_category=tbl_category.cat_id');
    $this->db->join('tbl_variant','tbl_product.p_color_variant=tbl_variant.v_id');
    $this->db->where('p_id',$id);
    $query=$this->db->get();


        return $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: what is the field that stored your option and post your options HTML code as well

Comment: category field code:<div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Category :</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <select name="cat" id="cat">
             
                  <option value="">--Select Category--</option>

                <?php foreach($cat as $c):?>
    
  <option value="<?php echo $c->cat_id?>"><?php echo $c->cat_name;?></option>
       <?php endforeach;?>
    
                </select>
                <h6 style="color:red"><?php echo form_error('cat')?></h6>
              </div>
            </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumptions**

`p_category` is your category id

**Code**

```
<select name="cat" id="cat">

    <option value="">--Select Category--</option>

    <?php 
        foreach($cat as $c):?>

        <option value="<?php echo $c->cat_id?>" <?php echo ($item[0]['p_category'] == $c->cat_id) ? 'selected' : '' ?>>
            <?php echo $c->cat_name;?>

            </option>
    <?php 
        endforeach;
    ?>

</select>
```

---

**Explain**

**Q -** What this if do in above `<?php echo ($item[0]['p_category'] == $c->cat_id) ? 'selected' : '' ?>`

**A -** Assume `$item[0]['p_category']` has *value 2* so when ever `$c->cat_id` equesl to that value its print `selected` keyword

Ex:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">aa</option>
    <option value="2" selected>bb</option>
    <option value="3">cc</option>
    <option value="4">dd</option>
</select>
```