# How to show dynamic value exist in selectpicker?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <?php
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('candidate_team');
        $where = "candidate_id='".$id."' and member_type='Recruiter'";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $qqs = $this->db->get();
        $result = $qqs->result_array();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['member_name'].'">'.$row['member_name'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

I have a multi-select dropdown. Now, What I want if a value exists in the database then the value already show in `select picker`. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: where you did this in view? if yes then it's wrong, if you are new in CI then you need to learn MVC otherwise you will get more issues in the future, so please try to learn it from CI Documentation, Normally DB related all the stuff will come from Model to Controller and Controller to view [ if you want to solve above thig First you need to get Members and create only select design with data then selected this will come ]

Comment: pass existing value from controller andcompare here, if match then make it selected.

Comment: Please refer this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46743947/how-to-show-selected-value-from-database-and-show-in-dropdownlist-using-codeigni]

Answer (score 0):

You need to get DB record in controller and then pass it to view to display with selectpicker

**Controller**

I'm supposing you've configured database

```
public function getselectpiker(){
    $this->load->model('model_name');
    $data['result'] = $this->model_name->get_data($id); // Pass candidate id here
    $this->load->view('file_name', $data);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function get_data($id){
    return $this->db->get_where('candidate_team', ['candidate_id' => $id,  'member_type' => 'Recruiter'])->result_array();
}
```

**View**

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
<?php
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['member_name'].'">'.$row['member_name'].'</option>';
    }
?>
```